# Google token usage on protected REST API

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on Flutter with Google Sign In and also have my own protected REST API running on Node JS. On Flutter, i am using google_sign_in lib and I can have both access token and id token. My understanding (reading from several sources) is that we should use access token for protected REST API (correct me if I am wrong).

On Node JS, I use google-auth-library lib for verification. However, it is like there is only one method for id token verification; `verifyIdToken`. It works fine if I pass id token to the request. I try to use access token and found the error `Wrong number of segments in token`.

Two questions

1. Should I use my own JWT on my protected REST API instead of Google access token?
2. How to verify Google access token on node JS